# Rear camera on in every gear

Tags: electrical, backup-camera, rear

Rear camera comes on in every gear although it has been wired correctly to reversing light cable.
There was no earth cable on the camera.Any ideas why this is? Regards How
Þhe rear camera has been wired to reverse light cable.tested with a lamp.Is it possible the power finds its way back to the rear camera from the front camera some how? I presume the rear camera is earthed fom the front camera via cigarette lighter socket which is reduced from 12 to 5.rennault kangoo 1.6 2008

Comment: Does that reverse light cable come on only when reverse is selected or is it live at all times?

Comment: Hi Mike  ,the reversing light only comes on in reverse but the camera comes on in all gears including reverse

Comment: Then I would guess that the camera is wired to the wrong cable or it is the wrong side of the reverse switch.

Comment: Year & model? Its possible the back up light is controlled via ground signal (meaning constant 12V at lamp) In this case its possible your cam is always on since its probably grounded where you have it hooked up or from the control box.

Comment: Renault kangoo 2008